# Mesh not bending smoothly to bones

Tags: rigging

As you can see the in the screenshot below the mesh is not bending smoothly according to the pose of the bones.

There are more than enough subdivisions. But the weight paint is irregular.

Link to blend file.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZNfettFy4mPaNWBkJT7hq_6CnJ4qBzoI

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a subdivision issue.
I cleared the parent, subdivided the plane and parented it again with automatic weights. It works fine then I think.

Edit: Here is the edited file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kZZFuC196PkZ_omzLCpyDzy4sQYdYoy3

[image]

Comment: Could you share the blend file?

Comment: @SurajSirohi I edited my answer with the link.

Comment: @SurajSirohi Well thanks for accepting the answer. I got to say that it was not the reason though. Because your  geometry is in fact enough. The reason is really the strange weight distribution that it receives on automatic weights. I don't know why, but apparently this is a workaround ...

Comment: you also used subD modifier.